# Woocommerce: how to save products SKU in orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Now the product SKU is related to the product, so when ordering and the product is not deleted it can be shown, but as soon as the product gets deleted the SKU is no longer available. Viewing orders can't show the SKU anymore.

Comment: the question here is what's the use of the sku if the product is already deleted?

Comment: it is needed for history, warranty, ...

Answer (score 4):

**Tested code**

use the `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` hook. I've included two versions. 1 that only supports simple products. The second version supports variations as well.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'so_28193771', 10, 3 );
function so_28193771( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

        $item_sku  =  get_post_meta( $values[ 'product_id' ], '_sku', true );

        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'sku', $item_sku , false );

}
```

[image: Product displayed on order receipt page]

[image: Database view of 'sku' added to order item meta successfully]

### Variation Support

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'so_28193771', 10, 3 );
function so_28193771( $item_id, $values, $cart_item_key ) {

        $item_sku  =  get_post_meta( $values[ 'product_id' ], '_sku', true );

        $item_has_variation  =  ( ! empty( $values[ 'variation_id' ] ) ? true : false );

        if( $item_has_variation ) {

                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'parent_sku', $item_sku, false );

                $variation_sku  =  get_post_meta( $values[ 'variation_id' ], '_sku', true );
                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'variation_sku', $variation_sku, false );

        }
        else {

                wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'sku', $item_sku , false );

        }

}
```

[image: Product displayed on order receipt page with variation]
[image: Database view of 'sku' added to order item meta successfully with variation]

Comment: I have a doubt . I have many meta details in each product in cart . I saved that meta details in  $cart_item_data. ....   $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( 21, 1, 0,  $item,$cart_item_data)    .. now how can i save this meta details to the order item ? . please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873176/woocommerce-need-to-save-cart-item-meta-of-the-each-product-to-orders

Answer (score 0):

As of 3.0.1, the woocommerce_add_order_item_meta hook has been deprecated and the new hook is woocommerce_new_order_item($item_id, $item, $order_id)